# Access remote service in different application

Tags: android

I defined a remote service over a AIDL file. Now i want to access this service in a different application. But how can I do that? The AIDL file is not accessible in my second application, and if i just copy the AIDL file, then the service can^^t be found.

Any hints for that problem??

Thanks Sebi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to copying the AIDL file into the other application, you need to advertise the service, via an `intent-filter` in the manifest, under a name (e.g., `action`) where your other application can reference it. See [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClient/) and [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteService/) for a sample client and service implementing this pattern.

Comment: yes i already used your code to implement the service but there is a problem:

the onStart Method of the Service is called, but the onServiceConnected() method on the client is never called and that's why me service object is always null

bindService returns true....

Comment: I can tell you that the code I linked to above works. I do not know why `onServiceConnected()` is not being called in your code.